# EC algorithm to derive bits/keys and sign/verify

Tags: encryption, aes, public-key

Looking at the question [“ECDSA vs ECIES vs ECDH”](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12823/ecdsa-vs-ecies-vs-ecdh) it appears that you can either have a tool that can derive keys or bits, or can be used to sign and verify something. Is there an EC way to do both with the same keypair?

Comment: The algorithms for key exchange and signing are different, but the algorithm for generating key-pairs is the same for both. So you certainly can use a key-pair for both, but if done incorrectly it might harm security. See [Using same keypair for Diffie-Hellman and signing](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3260/using-same-keypair-for-diffie-hellman-and-signing)

Comment: I've voted as dupe, but note that ECIES is basically **ephemeral-static ECDH** + symmetric encryption, something that may not be directly clear from the other question.